# to use rowspan in the javascript program

Tags: javascript, html, css

how can i use rowspan or colspan so that the first two columns are as it is(i.e the first 2 columns of single row are present for only once and the other rows repeated for multiple times) and the remaining rows be repeated for 7 times......i am using the insertcell method in my program.....or else can i get some ideas where i could make the last row bottom border to be thick...in the above program it is being repeated 7 times ......[expected table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjmVP.png)

```js
function display() {

  var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

  for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();

    var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '70px';

    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '50px';

    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt_" + i + "' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '75px';


    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence_" + i + "'  name= 'oralcommence'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '65px';


    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' ' id = 'amtgiv_" + i + "'  name= 'amtgiv'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '75px';

    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'urine_" + i + "' name= 'urine'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '60px';

    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'remarks_" + i + "' name= 'remarks'  required></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '50px';

    newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
    newCell.innerHTML = "<tr><td><i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i></td></tr>";
    newCell.style.width = '50px';

  }


}
```

```css
#myTable1 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#myTable1 th {
  background-color: #009999;
  color: black;
  width: 210px;
}

.table-fixed {}

#myTable1 .tbody1 {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#myTable1 thead,
.tbody1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed table-hover table-condensed" style="width: 1200px; align: center;" id="myTable1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Date Comm.</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Drug</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Dosage</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Route Of Admin</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Ordered By</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:130px;">Time</th>
      <th rowspan='2' style="width:50px;">Delete</th>


    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody1">
  </tbody>
  <tr id="hiderow">
    <td><button onclick="display()"></button></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: there must be some dummy data in it to test and debug the problem .. with no data its time taking we enter data to test it according to your flow of work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the display function:

```
    function display() {

        var tableRef = document.getElementById('myTable1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];

        for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            var rowsAdd = tableRef.insertRow();
                if (i<1)
            {
                var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML="<input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'time' name= 'time'  required>";
            newCell.rowSpan=7;
            newCell.style.width = '70px';

                var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML="<input form ='forma'  class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oraltype'  name= 'oraltype' required>";
            newCell.rowSpan=7;
            newCell.style.width = '50px';
            }
                var newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML="<input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'oralamt_" + i + "' name= 'oralamt'  required></td></tr>";
            newCell.style.width = '75px';

            newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML = "<input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' id = 'oralcommence_" + i + "'  name= 'oralcommence'  required>";
            newCell.style.width = '65px';

            newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML = "<input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm' ' id = 'amtgiv_" + i + "'  name= 'amtgiv'  required>";
            newCell.style.width = '75px';

            newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML = "<input  form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text' id = 'urine_" + i + "' name= 'urine'  required>";
            newCell.style.width = '60px';

            newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML = "<input form ='forma' class= 'form-control input-sm'  type='text'  id = 'remarks_" + i + "' name= 'remarks'  required>";
            newCell.style.width = '50px';

            newCell = rowsAdd.insertCell();
            newCell.innerHTML = "<i class='fa fa-trash-o' style='font-size:20px'  onclick='deleteRow(this)'></i>";
            newCell.style.width = '50px';


        }


    }
```

You may see the demo in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/h1j4fmqn/).